# Unexpected Token, expected } even though all the braces have matching pairs

Tags: javascript, react-native

Not sure why it is asking for a brace there. As far as i can tell all the braces are matched. Is it because of a closing tag is wrong somewhere? I am pretty new to react native so I am having trouble understanding some of the basic formatting that is required.

```
import React, { Component, Header } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';

export default class App extends Component {

  render () {
    return (
      <View 
      style={styles.contain}>

        <Button style={styles.leagueButton} title='League Of Legends' />
        <Button style={styles.contain} title='CSGO'  />
        <Button style={styles.overwatchButton} title='Overwatch' />
        <Button style={styles.dota2Button} title='Overwatch' />
        <Button style={styles.fortniteButton} title='Fortnite' />
      <View/>

      <Header>
          centerComponent={{ text: 'Games', style: { color: '#fff'  } }}

        <Header/>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  leagueButton: {
    top: 50
  },
  contain: {
    top: 70
  },
  overwatchButton: {
    top: 90
  },
  dota2Button: {
    top: 110
  },
  fortniteButton:{
    top: 130
  }

})
```

Update:Now I get a JSX closing tag error after adding another header tag

[image: Updated error image]

Update again: Render error picture

[image: Render error]

Comment: Do you not need a semicolon after `return`?

Comment: @Gendarme No, semicolons aren't necessary in some situations due to ASI (but it's not a good thing to rely on)

Comment: <View />  ===> </View>?

Comment: @VincentRamdhanie If I change it to that I will get an adjacent JSX elements error because it needs to be wrapped in an enclosing tag. I thought that was the issue originally but cant figure out a workaround for it

Comment: @trognanders yes that is what it is supposed to be. What do you mean by the definition using it?

Comment: @trognanders It is a component from the react-native-elements module. Could it be the mix of modules that is causing it? I am not set on using the Header from that module if there is an easier way to get a banner across the top of the screen with text in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <Header>
          centerComponent={{ text: 'Games', style: { color: '#fff'  } }}

        <Header/>
```

Problem is u closed off the `Header` tag which im guessing the `centerComponent` is the props of it?

**UPDATES:**

```
return (
      <View 
      style={styles.contain}>

        <Button style={styles.leagueButton} title='League Of Legends' />
        <Button style={styles.contain} title='CSGO'  />
        <Button style={styles.overwatchButton} title='Overwatch' />
        <Button style={styles.dota2Button} title='Overwatch' />
        <Button style={styles.fortniteButton} title='Fortnite' />
      <View/>

      <Header>
          centerComponent={{ text: 'Games', style: { color: '#fff'  } }}

        <Header/>
    )
```

There is only one level of tag can be returned but you're returning both `View` and `Header` at the same level. So instead you should wrap both into another `View`

```
return (
     <View>
      <View style={styles.contain}>
        <Button style={styles.leagueButton} title='League Of Legends' />
        <Button style={styles.contain} title='CSGO'  />
        <Button style={styles.overwatchButton} title='Overwatch' />
        <Button style={styles.dota2Button} title='Overwatch' />
        <Button style={styles.fortniteButton} title='Fortnite' />
      </View>

      <Header 
        centerComponent={{ text: 'Games', style: { color: '#fff'  } }}
      />
    </View>)
```

Comment: changing it to that gives me an adjacent jsx elements error right at the <Header> declaration

Comment: @bills the error you’re trying to avoid needs to be dealt with - you need a single parent element. Your workaround is causing your current error.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll Ok I see what you mean about the parent elements. Adding another <view> throws another JSX closing tag error for <header> though. Is it because of the same reason as the first error?

Comment: @bills you’ll need to properly close your Header and View components with `</Header>` and `</View>`

Comment: @bills: From your picture you are having a typo `<Header/>`. Should be `</Header>` instead

Comment: @Isaac doing that brings us back to square one with the original error with the expected } tag...

Comment: @bills: Can you try again on the last code snippet, directly copy pasting?

Comment: @Isaac It still isnt working. Looks like a render issue. I added a picture of the error

Comment: @bills: Instead of importing `Header` from `react`, you should import `Header` from `react-native-elements`

Comment: @Issac WOW! I cant believe I missed that.... That was the issue. Thank you.

Comment: @bills You can also wrap your `<Header>` and `<View>` with a single `<React.Fragment> </React.Fragment>`.  Check my answer please.

Answer (score 0):

You can also wrap your `<Header>` and `<View>` with a single `<React.Fragment> </React.Fragment>`. That should fix your error.

Put that around your head and view instead of another `<View> </View>` or ' ' etc.

It basically wraps your stuff together so that you return only one parent div (to meet jsx requirements) but without needing you to wrap your child components with an actual div or higher order component.

The react fragment tag will disappear at the DOM in effect but still allow you to wrap your same level tags under one parent. In the latest versions of react you can also use the new, shorter syntax:

```
<> 
 // Your other components / tags
</>
`.
```